# Highlight selected tab in menu bar <li> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

Can anybody help me? I have the menu bar:

```
<nav id="menu" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">Categories</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://mysite/component" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Components</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-inner">
     <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="http://mysite/mouse">Mice</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://mysite/monitor">Monitors</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://mysite/printer">Printers</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
              <a href="http://mysite/component" class="see-all">Show All Components</a> </div>
        </li>

<li><a href="http://mysite/tablet">Tablets</a></li>
<li><a href="http://mysite/software">Software</a></li>
<li><a href="http://mysite/smartphone">Phones</a></li>
<li><a href="http://mysite/camera">Cameras</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

stylesheet for this menu bar:

```
#menu {
    background-color: #8a6d3b;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bba784, #8a6d3b);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #c7b595 #8a6d3b #8e6318;
    min-height: 40px;
}
```

I need highlight selected tabs (**Components, Tablets, Software, Phones, Cameras**) in this menu bar. 
For this I have tried to use this script:

```
$(function(){

    var url = window.location.href; 

    $("#menu a").each(function() {
         if(url == (this.href)) { 
            $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

and this style:

```
#menu .nav > li.active > a  {
    background-color: #e0c698;
}
```

For the Tabs: **Tablets, Software, Phones, Cameras**. this working fine. But for **Components** tab who has `<div class="dropdown-inner">` does not work.
Can you help me to find solution?

Comment: you can simply use class="active"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the `:last` from `parents()` to get the main `<li>` if you are in any of the sub list inside main `<li>` to apply the active class.

Change your js code from

```
$(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
```

to

```
$(this).parents("li:last").addClass("active");
```

By this even if the url is from sub menus it will add the `active` class to main `<li>`.

below is the demo where `url is from monitor li` and its adding active class to `Components`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = 'http://mysite/monitor'; 
    $("#menu a").each(function() {
         if(url == (this.href)) { 
            $(this).parents("li:last").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  background-color: #8a6d3b;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bba784, #8a6d3b);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #c7b595 #8a6d3b #8e6318;
  min-height: 40px;
}

#menu .nav > li.active > a {
  background-color: #e0c698;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu" class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">Categories</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="http://mysite/component" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Components</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <div class="dropdown-inner">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="http://mysite/mouse">Mice</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://mysite/monitor">Monitors</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://mysite/printer">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <a href="http://mysite/component" class="see-all">Show All Components</a> </div>
      </li>

      <li><a href="http://mysite/tablet">Tablets</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://mysite/software">Software</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://mysite/smartphone">Phones</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://mysite/camera">Cameras</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Tnak you. Working. I have changed `var url = 'http://mysite/monitor';` to `var url = window.location.href;` and all ok.

Answer (score 0):

> But for Components tab who has  does not
>   work. Can you help me to find solution?

It is because you are selector is giving `background-color` of **direct descendants** of `.nav`, **so descendants of `dropdown-inner` are missed out**.

Make it

```
#menu .nav li.active > a  { //removed > after .nav
    background-color: #e0c698;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

  var url = 'http://mysite/mouse'; //window.location.href;

  $("#menu a").each(function() {
    //console.log(url + ' ' + this.href);
    
    if (url == (this.href)) {
      $(this).parent("li").addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  background-color: #8a6d3b;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bba784, #8a6d3b);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #c7b595 #8a6d3b #8e6318;
  min-height: 40px;
}

#menu li.active > a {
  background-color: #e0c698;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu" class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs">Categories</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="http://mysite/component" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Components</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <div class="dropdown-inner">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="http://mysite/mouse">Mice</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://mysite/monitor">Monitors</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://mysite/printer">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <a href="http://mysite/component" class="see-all">Show All Components</a> </div>
      </li>

      <li><a href="http://mysite/tablet">Tablets</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://mysite/software">Software</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://mysite/smartphone">Phones</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://mysite/camera">Cameras</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: not exactly this I want to achieve. I need to highlite Components tab only when something from dropdown menu in this tab is selelected.